# What Type of cable is this?

Tags: cables

I know someone who needs a longer version (12ft) of this cable for their TV, but I do not know what type it is. Can someone please identify the ends for me so I know what to shop for?

The cable is has this written on it:

```
LWC 20-CMR-SD  HDTV SERIAL DIGITAL 20 AWG CMR(UL) C(UL) E113333 ER22211 MADE IN USA
```

[image: One End]
[image: Other End]

Thanks!

Comment: http://libertycable.com/RUB_IMAGES/images/spec/20-CMR-VIDEO%20Specification.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top connector is an "F" connector - common cablevision connector.

The second connector looks like an "RCA Phono" connector, often used for audio and video interconnects on consumer equipment.

I expect the cable is RG-59 coax or equivalent.